# Missing template/view file in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-5, routes, visual-studio-2015, angular-template

Im creting MVC5(asp.net)+angularjs web application with Visual Studio 2015.The problem is:
When link http://localhost:56028/#/phones/1 is loaded, I want to read file `jsons/1.json`, but error appears that it's missing, but file is there.

What is wrong?

My files are:

- /app/firstApp.js
- /app/jsons/1.json
- /app/controllers/testController.js (it contains function PhoneDetailController)
- /app/partials/phone-detail.html

firstApp.js with routing:

```
 var app = angular.module('BulletinBoardApp', [
        'ngRoute',
        'testControllers'
    ]);

    app.config(['$routeProvider',
      function ($routeProvider) {
          $routeProvider.
            when('/phones', {
                templateUrl: '/app/partials/phone-list.html',
                controller: 'PhoneListController'
            }).
            when('/phones/:phoneId', {
                templateUrl: '/app/partials/phone-detail.html',
                controller: 'PhoneDetailController'
            }).
            otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/phones'
            });
      }]);
```

PhoneDetailController (file testController.js):

```
 testControllers.controller('PhoneDetailController', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$http',
      function ($scope, $routeParams, $http) {
          $http.get('../jsons/' + $routeParams.phoneId + '.json')
              .success(function (data) {
                  $scope.phone = data;
              }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                  alert(data + "; " + status + "; " + headers + "; " + config);
              })
      }]);
```

**Update1**:

My main html file is:
\View\Layout_layout.cshtml , 
this is ASP MVC file, but this is displayed properly

**Update2**:

I tried:

```
$http.get('/app/jsons/' + $routeParams.phoneId + '.json')
$http.get('../app/jsons/' + $routeParams.phoneId + '.json')
$http.get('../../app/jsons/' + $routeParams.phoneId + '.json')
```

and some others configurations but they are not working.

**Update3**:

I tried to read 2 json files: 1.json (it exists) and 2.json( missing). For missing file, status method gives 404 and data gives 404 page, but for 1.json, status is undefined and data is undefined. Why?

Comment: try `$http.get('jsons/' + $routeParams.phoneId + '.json')`...

Comment: I already checked this with no success

Comment: it's not working even for `$http.get('/app/jsons/' + $routeParams.phoneId + '.json')`

Comment: `/app/jsons/1.json` and `/index.html`, is it?

Comment: I added update for it in post

Comment: the url with "/" prefix is relative to the domain, without the "/" prefix it will be relative to the main ("index.html") page or base url (if you use location in the html5 mode).